# FormView ItemUpdating with Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Checkbox and FormView bound on ItemUpdating event with an Update button. I have other fields as well that save, only the Checkbox does not save True or False to the database. How do I make it save as well?

Comment: can you post your aspx markup and C# code.

Comment: I figured it out... I had <%# Eval... instead of <%# Bind.